# How to install Mirador when node generates warnings and asks to commit a file

Tags: npm, iiif

I'm having issues trying to install and run Mirador through Node. I changed the directory but when I get it to install is generates the warnings copied below. I'd appreciate any help in resolving the issue!

Kind regards,

Trisha

`Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 9.9.0 (x64) and npm.`

```
C:\Users\user>npm install -g grunt-cli
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt -> 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt + grunt-cli@1.2.0 added 16 packages in 4.873s    

C:\Users\user>cd mirador
The system cannot find the path specified. 

C:\Users\user>cd: mirador
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user>cd C:\Users\user\Downloads\mirador-develop

C:\Users\user\Downloads\mirador-develop>npm install npm WARN saveError 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\mirador-
develop\package.json' npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. 
You should commit this file. npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\mirador-develop\package.json'
npm WARN mirador-develop No description
npm WARN mirador-develop No repository field.
npm WARN mirador-develop No README data
npm WARN mirador-develop No license field.

up to date in 0.125s

C:\Users\user\Downloads\mirador-develop>
```

Comment: So, do I assume correctly that the `C:\Users\user\Downloads\mirador-develop` directory was created by running something like `cd C:\Users\user\Downloads; git clone https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador.git` ? Do I assume correctly that the last command was just `npm install` and not `npm install WARN saveError`? If yes, the answer is to first locate the file named `package.json` somewhere under that `mirador-
develop` directory, `cd` there and run `npm install`.

Comment: And yet the question is: do you really need to hack on Mirador? I mean, that project is available through the npm repository, so you can just do `npm install mirador` to have it downloaded with all its dependencies, so do you really need to clone it by hand?

Comment: Thank you @kostix for replying. Yes, I was trying to download mirador from GitHub. And the last command was npm install. I followed the instructions suggested on the GitHub webpage for downloading Mirador. The last install command triggered the warnings. I would rather not clone it by hand, if it is available through the npm directory I would prefer to download it with all its dependencies.

Comment: Hi again @kostix, thanks for the suggestions but neither open seem to be working. I tried locating the package-json file in npm and installing it but it won't work and installing mirador directly didn't work either.

Comment: What I proposed is to try to install mirador from the npm package repository—not from Github repository. I mean [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) explains how to install from the package repository (I mean the option "c" there). Basically you'd need to do run `npm install mirador` while not being in its cloned directory (you don't need one). It should grab the package from the repository and all its dependencies, transitively.